# How to make an addEventListener for an element that does not render on page load work?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an input element that renders after you click a button, i.e., it does not render on page load.
When a user types something into the element, it is supposed to console log "Add button clicked!".
However, I get the below error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "addEventListener", document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Below is the code:

```
export const renderTodo = () => {
    document.querySelector('#main').innerHTML = `
<h2>Todo(CRUD) Page ${import.meta.env.VITE_TEST}</h2>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="New todo.." id="new-todo">
    <br>
    <button id="add-todo">Add</button>
</form> 
`;
};

document.getElementById("new-todo").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log("Add button clicked!");
});
```

How do I get the addEventListener to work?

Comment: [This is probably relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). There's a strong focus on jQuery in that question, but some answers provide plain JavaScript solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error is throwing** because as we are **trying to access** `document.getElementById("new-todo")` before it was attached to the HTML DOM as the `function renderTodo()` was not called and we tried to access the `document.getElementById("new-todo")`.

```js
export const renderTodo = () => {
    document.querySelector('#main').innerHTML = `
<h2>Todo(CRUD) Page ${import.meta.env.VITE_TEST}</h2>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="New todo.." id="new-todo">
    <br>
    <button id="add-todo">Add</button>
</form> 
`;
// after the HTML string is parsed and attached in DOM then apply. It will be called whenever the function is called.
  document.getElementById("new-todo").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      console.log("Add button clicked!");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `addEventListener()` from inside the `renderToDo` block:

```
export const renderTodo = () => {
    document.querySelector('#main').innerHTML = `
<h2>Todo(CRUD) Page ${import.meta.env.VITE_TEST}</h2>
<br>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="New todo.." id="new-todo">
    <br>
    <button id="add-todo">Add</button>
</form> 
`;

document.getElementById("new-todo").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log("Add button clicked!");
});
};
```